# QML module no found

Tags: qt, qml, embedded-linux

I am attempting to execute a program which uses qt qml on rockchip Linux. I have just added Qt5Charts to the runtime environment. On execution i get :

```
[W] MyApp  - QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
[W] MyApp  - qrc:/qml/main.qml:103 Type MediaViewerScene unavailable
qrc:/qml/MediaScene.qml:3 module "QtCharts" version 5.9 is not installed
```

I have in /usr/lib:
libQtCharts5, libQtCharts5.9, libQtCharts5.9.1
and in /usr/qml/QtCharts:

designer            plugins.qmltypes
libqtchartsqml2.so  qmldir

I think I may have not adb pushed a required file.

```
This is /usr/qml/QtCharts/designer/default]# ls

AreaSeries.qml                  PieSeries.qml
BarSeries.qml                   PolarAreaSeries.qml
BoxPlotSeries.qml               PolarLineSeries.qml
HorizontalBarSeries.qml         PolarScatterSeries.qml
HorizontalPercentBarSeries.qml  PolarSplineSeries.qml
HorizontalStackedBarSeries.qml  ScatterSeries.qml
LineSeries.qml                  SplineSeries.qml
PercentBarSeries.qml            StackedBarSeries.qml
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could test with a ready-made Qt Charts QML example like https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-example.html to exclude possible issues in your own application, e.g. charts module not being added to your pro file/cmakelists.txt, charts requiring QApplication instead of QGuiApplication...

Comment: There is actually no Qt Charts code, except import QtCharts 5.9.  So far,  nothing executable. Just trying to run on the target with Charts included.

Comment: I still suggest you to to test with proven code. You say you just added "import QtCharts 5.9" but the problem is there is no such module version for charts like 5.9. Maybe try with  "import QtCharts 2.1" as in the example I linked. Btw, obviously the highest version you can use with Qt 5.9 is charts 2.2: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/qtcharts-index.html